# When your application is opened from notification is it possible to get back to previous application from where it was opened? Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-intent, notifications

Is it possible to return to previous application from where your application is opened? 
For example I am in application A then I click on notification and open my application B then in my application B I click a button and I get back to application A? Currently I am trying to do that and the only way how I achieved is when my application is running in background or it only works for the first time.

I am using Flutter but these actions are executed in native Android code so I am probably missing something.

For getting back to previous app I am using: 
`moveTaskToBack(true);`

For creating a notification my code looks like this:

```
private void NotifyToAutofill(String uri, String url, NotificationManager notificationManager) {
        if (notificationManager == null || isNullOrWhitespace(uri)) {
            return;
        }

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_RUN);

        startIntent.putExtra("uri", uri);
        startIntent.putExtra("url", url.contains("\u2022")
                || url.contains("\u2731") ? "" : url);
        String channelId = "channel-01";
        String channelName = "test";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, channelName, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        int color = 0x008000;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle("Test Service")
                .setContentText("Tap to open application")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(startIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(AutoFillNotificationId, notification);

    }
```

Comment: Yes is possible if you app no longer available or large memory need then possible to destroy your app.

Comment: What do you mean no longer available? I just want to do it programmatically, I tried movetaskbackto(true) and onBackPressed() but it still will not work

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. My problem was that i was creating **PendingIntent** with

```
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(startIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
```

Everything worked as intented when I used:

```
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```